# How to add text on facebook messenger bot before Welcome screen?

Tags: facebook, bots, facebook-messenger

Currently Facebook provides us with API to set a text or generic message as welcome screen which gets triggered when we press "Get Started" button in message window. However, some bots show some text on top of get started button (as soon as we click message button). How is it done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. Its called Greeting message and it can be added on page setting itself.

Comment: Do you know how the buttons before the greeting message are generated and how can they can be customized?   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56951760/how-to-customize-the-buttons-shown-on-the-messenger-bot-welcome